# How do you force a subclass to initialize a superclass property at compile-time?

Tags: java, jsf

I have an abstract superclass with a property that must be set by the subclass for proper operation of instances...

```
abstract SuperClass {
  // this list must be initialized by the subclass
  List<? extends SavedSearch> savedSearches;
}
```

This abstract superclass has methods that operate on the savedSearches but it's up to the subclass to ensure that list is properly initialized.

What's the best way to do this?

It's easy with Java create superclass *methods* that must be implemented by subclasses, but not properties.  I thought about requiring an abstract initSavedSearch method like this in the superclass...

```
abstract initSavedSearchList();
```

... but that seemed strange, the subclass implementer is under no obligation to do anything in their method implementation, they could just do nothing.

I know I can code up some runtime checks to make sure the savedSearch list is init'd before running code in the superclass, but I'm hoping for compile-time checks (akin to to abstract methods) not runtime checks.

I saw a C# answer to a similar question which suggests hiding the default (zero-arg) constructor and creating a constructor in the abstract class that requires the list as an arg.  That sounds decent for Java, too.  But my particular class is a JSF 1.x managed bean.  I'm a JSF newbie, but AFAIK there's no easy way to get JSF to call a non-standard constructor for Managed Beans.

Is there a way to do this where I get some compile-time help to ensure that implementing subclasses are properly initializing a superclass property?

Thanks!

- Gary

Comment: Why not just put the initialization code in the superclass' constructor, and then invoke `super(...)` when initializing the subclass?

Comment: A couple of reasons.  This is a JSF bean so the dependencies are provided by the framework.  Those dependencies are not provided at constructor-time.  The list in question needs a database connection (provided after construction) to init.

Comment: Probably more to the point, though, is that
I don't *want* my superclass constructor to do the init.  It doesn't know how to init the property, that's the job of the implementing subclasses.  They'll each init the list in different ways.  This was what I meant when I said "it's up to the subclass to ensure that list is properly initialized."

Comment: Passing a database connection around like that is a very bad practice. Lookup the DAO pattern or step over to EJB/JPA.

Comment: BalusC: the subclass needs dependencies to do it's job.  It needs a DAO.  That's instantiated elsewhere and injected into the class.  This is good practice AFAIK.  Constructors run before dependency injection occurs (unless you're injecting *via* constructors which we're not doing and probably can't do).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One of the ways is to provide a constructor which takes that as argument.

```
public abstract class SuperClass {

    private List<SavedSearch> savedSearches;

    protected SuperClass(List<SavedSearch> savedSearches) {
        this.savedSearches = savedSearches;
        // You can do additional checks here on null, size(), etc.
    }

}
```

The subclasser is required to invoke that constructor.

```
public class SubClass extends SuperClass {

    public SubClass() {
        super(initAndGetSavedSearchesSomehow());
    }

}
```

Comment: Yah, that's the C# answer I was referring to.  It's a good answer for the general case.  But it doesn't work for this case (a JSF managed bean).  At least I don't think so, I need to know more about JSF to answer that definitively but I suspect JSF doesn't allow you to create Managed beans with non-default constructors that require arguments.

Comment: It definitely works for JSF. It will invoke the `SubClass` bean's default constructor. Note that you can't make an abstract class like `SuperClass` a managed bean. So don't let you confuse by that. Just try and experience it yourself :)

Comment: Ahh, I see.  I wasn't understanding that the initAndGetSavedSearchesSomehow() method returns a list that's being provided to the superclasses non-default constructor.  Got it.

Comment: BalusC: I think I've digested your suggestion.  But I'm still not clear how this helps.  The superclass can create a 1-arg constructor and the subclass can call it in its own default (zero-arg) constructor.  That's clear.  But there's no compile-time assurance that the subclass' default constructor calls that superclass' 1-arg constrcutor, right?

Comment: The class won't compile if the subclass' default constructor doesn't `super()` the superclass' constructor.

Comment: 1. Must hide the superclass' default constructor by making it private.  If you don't then the subclass is free to just do default constructor behavior and ignore the superclass' special 1-arg constructor.

Comment: 2. Must do setup in a separate class method.  
 Super is the first thing that has to be called in the subclass constructor so you can't put the setup code in your subclass constructor (you can't put any code before the super(...) call.  I thought BalusC was just being terse with super(initAndGetSavedSearchesSomehow()).  He wasn't, that syntax is required.

Comment: 3. initAndGetSavedSearchesSomehow() is a *static* class method.
That's a no-duh (this is a constructor we're talking about, instance methods are not yet available).  But I just wanted to note that the initAndGetSavedSearchesSomehow() must be static.

Comment: 1) That's only necessary when you've explicitly declared a default c'tor. You can also just remove it altogether if it's doing nothing. 2) You could alternatively also provide an abstract method in the superclass. 3) It doesn't need to be a static method. Your confusion is caused by something else.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3286/discussion-between-gary-affonso-and-balusc)